# How to click on an element inside a custom element (webcomponent)?

Tags: javascript, integration-testing, puppeteer, web-component, custom-element

I need to click a button inside a shadow root and that I cannot just write a query to do that. Is there any way to get that done?

According to the puppeteer docs, I can only pass a string-selector to the click method: https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.1.1&show=api-pageclickselector-options

You can see the button I need to click here: https://patterns.axa.ch/iframe.html?id=components-molecules-cookie-disclaimer--cookie-disclaimer (Please note, that this banner will go away when you click it and that you have to clear the storage. Better just use a private window.)

Comment: I'm running Chromium 82 and I can't view your button at all on https://patterns.axa.ch/iframe.html?id=components-molecules-cookie-disclaimer--cookie-disclaimer. Clicking on a button that is in a Shadow Root works out of the box.
See here for a demo https://lego.js.org/demo/index.html and it's sources: https://github.com/Polight/lego/blob/master/demo/bricks/x-button.html I'm not sure in what context this is not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way that works for me, but is hacky. Just use the native `HTMLElement.click()` method within the browser context (page.evaluate...). You can directly fire an event on a target.

If you have a better idea, please share!

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  const acceptButton = document.querySelector('axa-cookie-disclaimer').shadowRoot.querySelector('axa-button');
  acceptButton.click();
});
```

Comment: Just remember you can not access a ``mode:"closed"`` component ``shadowRoot`` Only option then (if you own the component!) is to add a method on it that handles your test interactions. [Wrap it in a ``console`` IIFE](https://davidwalsh.name/console-log-debug)  so it never ends up in production code. It is possible to inject such code in 3rd party (minified) source-code of components.. but it is a pain

Comment: I have done that **server-side** to inject *"peeking inside"* code into an element; then send the 'new' JS file to the Browser. Note that components *can* be build without the typical usage of Custom Element methods.. loads of edge cases and head aches.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I don't know if I've ever seen a closed shadow dom outside of tutorials. :D But thanks for your comment.